# Dual Boot Windows and Ubuntu on 2 separate drives Not working

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have a Dell Vostro 5581 laptop with Windows 10 installed.12GB RAM installed.  Recently I installed a 500GB M.2 NVME SSD card. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on this drive. So the 2 operating systems are on different drives. I have set the BIOS to startup from Ubuntu (i.e. made that the first drive) and then the Windows drive second. I have disabled fast startup in Windows as well. When I boot-up up the laptop goes straight into Windows. I can see the Ubuntu SSD in Windows Disk Management.

I had the same setup on my previous HP laptop and it worked fine. What could be the issue here? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: UEFI settings > Boot menu, make sure "Ubuntu" (Grub) is selected, that should be all.